# Is it possible to merge Data URIs in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, merge, data-uri

I have an array of Data URIs (PNG Image) and also have an array of their dimension information. Is it possible to merge two data uris into one image? How?

I tried Googling for the answer, but can't find a working example.

EDIT:
Here is a sample array

```
var data = [];

data.push([]);

data[0] = [];

data[0].push("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABAAAAAJ/CAYAAADmuaGtAAAgAElEQVR4XuzdCdwkRX34/3p2YdkFFheRQ5aAILfKIQhGRVwFPIGAZ4QIiImIUf9qPGLwl3/UeGD0F02iGGMEAnhEQEGjXOJBEBBFUHGRS5BdThVZjt2F3efXNUsN9dRW1bequ6ePmc+8XibsdHcd76qZp7/fru6Zetpuu08rXggggAACCCCAAAIIIIAAAggg0GmBS374g0rtmyIBUMmPgxFAAAEEEEAAAQQQQAABBBBoRIAEQCPMVIIAAggggAACCCCAAAIIIIBAuwIkANr1p3YEEEAAAQQQQAABBBBAAAEEGhEgAdAIM5UggAACCCCAAAIIIIDApAncfPPNk9Zl+ttxgSW3/bZSC3kGQCU+DkYAAQQQQAABBLolcM3VP5vRoJ9eeZv69Cd+qC75/sxAZs+9Fqq3vnM/NWfObLXvs7ZRi6+9Ux184BfU9KOPh973T7dWl//oVrXTLpuqcy94g5o1a2pQ7m6779GtDtMaBEYooBMAv/2tDrj0B2PNZ4AnqI8QnKJFgdlrpmHpFwmA0nQciAACCCCAAAIIdE/ATgB8+hM/KIL/S9Zq5Fvf+Zwi+H/u4P0jXn6aOv3MI9Wb33CmOu9/rhvue/rXjlBHvOJ09a+fP1y96KU7D98nAdC9MadFoxN4LAHwWB0V46/RNZaSJ0JgquIEJAEwEdOETiKAAAIIIIDApAi4KwB++L2bBisArvrJkhkEz9l/28EKgFcdcqp6/wcOVB/6+wuGV//1jjcsfZ/6wAnnqxOKbebqv36fBMCkzCT6qQV8CQBkEGhT4NHFWMEmnHPOOeqQQw4JbicB0OboUTcCCCCAAAIIIFCzwNO2/5tBYK+X9evXJz5ysXrHe5+nriiW8+tEgF7Wr1/veO/+6pMf/b7SV/p97+tbAN7yjueoZz77STPK2X2PPWtuMcUh0F0BEgDdHZtJbVksAaCDf/MKJQFIAEzqzKHfCCCAAAIIIDCWAg/e/apBv4594z7qoJfspF596H+pz538SvWCg3YYvP8fn71Mnf/t69RXzzlK/eXrvqo+f+qa/d33L77wBm85b3/XK8fSjU4h4BMgAcC86JpAKAFgB/+xJEAtCYCnPu+latHRb1PzNpgf9XnogWXq4pM/pX7xvW91zZH2IFC7wLpz5qgFGz9+UO7dd94xo/znH/SSwQNkLj7/f2qvlwIRQAABBCZbYLsnvrW4cr+fev6B26tjXvvlwcP/nrrbFuqDH3vx4Eq/Duy/eMZr1H7P2079/OrbB1i+99//nm97y7np9k9PNjC9nygBEgATNdy96KwvAeAL/kNJgFoSAG/8t7PU4zZ7YjLYia/8U3HfvffeWx15xGvV/Pnz1bJly9Q3zjlXXXzxxeJxuTv85xf+Q33jG+cU5T+2XGJYxo4HqqmdDvQWOX3uu3OrGu4/dciJavqem5S69KTSZUzqgds+eQe177P3D3b/ovO+VQTba05m2n5tuvkT1Qte+NJBM8788qnDZMCDD9yvDj78NYP3v3zqf7TdTOpHAAEEEBgzAbMCwHTLPO1fJwNyXvrWAN+vA6y/6VfFYr79nfNm7PPiF71w+O+y28RKa9hBt81uaw1FrlWEr46YySjakFJmWYuyx6W0qY19UhMAy+6/X917733qwYeWq/XnzVULFmyk5m+4YRtNps4xF5CeASB1v5YEgFRJ7nYd/OvA/Morr1Q/Lv635ZZbqkOLBxm8/tg3DN4z282/c8u399cPyvnsSSepz37WE4zvfaSatfdfeItffdJjf8hy65913HlqeunVavqc8kmE3DrHYf8FG29SBP/PVd89/1vq4ZUr1+qSTg7sufcz1XnfOls9UHwJt/3aceenqKfvsybZddONv1bbPXnHwX9f96tfDNv/i6t/2nYzqR8BBBBAYMwE7ASA/bT/7bf8sNL39ZtnA+ifBzQ/Deh7X7/n+3UAKQEQCnB1YF12WxNDZILwUSYAfHXETJrod6iOsoF82ePa7Gus7pQEwM23/ra4YPmAesImGxdB/wZq2f0PqHt+94fBf2+7zZ90tWu0q6cCnUgALPqHs0W+Bx9erf64fNVgv8X/tOZes9Drgx/8gNp5p53UK1/16uEuZiWAfqPpBMDqK/9LqStPE/uYuoOdAJjecjc1tfSatQ+dv7ma3nBzNXW7Z1tqRaH9irIHr2V3Vi2pseM3KDKoiw56qbrk4gvVvX/4XbDePZ/xTLXZZluo717wP94kwaga/NTdn14kHZap+4vEg77qv2LlCvWzH1+mbr7x+kGV9moArvqPahQoFwEEEEBAC7grAOyn/euHA+r/6dcXTrpcfeQDFw3+O/S+79cBpASAbxRMUJgb7DYVTMbaV9esCtXRVB9z+1G2XWWPy21fU/tLCYBblyxVK4sLU9tuvZWaPXudYbNWrXpE3XzrbWpOcUvo1gu3TGru1//nwrX2+7OXHJB0bF076Tbk1um2O3S82U8qv0wb6up/H8rpRQLADv41akoCYO+99lYvfslLvGPw31/9itqpSBAsXrxYnX76GYPl+3qFwHHHHacWFh+wJcUH8fTTT1enFf8zL739kEMOHtxSoFcVnHTS5wa3FtgrAExi4f3v/z9rbgl4dAVAKAEw9YrPqKknPFmt/u4/KfWbH6mpI04ZVDf9tePXBNfWCoLp++5Uq8/7BzX1uxvVIAFQ/Futt4GaWm9DNb3ifrW6WA2gt6kiOJ866P+oqU23H7Z99f8WqxN+vibJMjy2+O+pjYokgVWu3q5vL5jacvdBmeq+OwblrDrnXWuSDHM2VFMvLMpeuPuadt59g5o+/wPRRIC+V32zLfxfWvpK9lVFkDvql76X/vkHvkT94pqr1JLf3iJW95znrfmivOR7a3+JigeX3OE1r3vDIOh/sJhTG2/yBHXXHUuLlQr++/vnrDdXLTrgRYOaLr7wO2rliuUla+UwBBBAAAEE1hb4/Ge/4X2qv94zJwEQ+nWAricA5s6bp1528CFql6c8rViKPU/95Mor1DfPPUctf+ghcbqkBq/rz11XHfn83dXTd1yoNpw7R/3gmpvVad+9Wj24/OHsOlLrFAuueQc7YaGLdldG2LctuLd4mH9LZZgmd+F8M8QXSwDoIP+aX16ndnvKTjOCf1OWtN2uMxT0Nh0M59bn2196L1aH2Zbbjpqnf6eL60QCoG4hHdzrIF8H8lde+WO1+Lrrivv/v6eWLl06qOrII45Q7373u9SJJ35cfbd4LoB+Xwf4OrjX++rVA3q7XkFwXfHvRYsWqU/98/8dLPVfWpT5pjcdp972/719sM0kAL773YvVF4rbDvRzBnQCYPB6NIAfBOvLHnuI2+pLP/dYsF4kAfRr+jeXqlk7HaSGwXrx/IBZz/8bNX3zpWq6COyniiv9098pgu2V9w+CeP1afc3ZakoH/Ns+a+YtAc86bhCUTxf/m/WsNxaB/hZq9X++PHysrqNILihT5z03Dtoz9bTDBgmGYQJg0TvXtFEnLIrkgb69YXpJcStC5HkG+sr7C196mJqz3nozhvn+4mr3ed88u5Gr7Dqgv+uO29WvF/8yaaoNEgbFaoG7imcBNJGg0I0yKwBuKxIU+lYFfYvCuuusM7gFYPny5er7F31n2PZ589ZXh77ytYN/f+O/z1APPfRgUr/YCQEEEEAAgRQBfW6jX76n+uvVAPvtv91g++U/uqVYMbfmSf++929Y+j5vOZdf/eGUZszYJ3b1W+8YWnZfJjj+i6OOVrsWwb/9+klxPvm1r8rPQEit7+2HP0vtVQT/9usHP/+N+vdv/Vi0cetwg+SYh1h4jTu4tyvY7Q71QVfv7mf3J+TbhfPNEF0sAaDv+19y+11q5x3WfKZ8r8XX36QWPnEz8XkAfUwApATyxsTeN+U4EgDhD3MnEgA7HloElJ7Xw4+sUnf+4SE1rR93br0e+tH/L349De77P/QQ9YzieQA6IaCD+5xnAOg/fmZ//TyBJUWSYBjYW7Xr/fRKgb332kvdfvvtg8TA8BV4BsAwoNY7FkH2rGcXAXvxsu/rN1fiTeBud9h9BsAwIWA9V0DfGqAfEz9rtz8rEgTPHgbxvmP11f7pLxYJgkfbO2yf8+/BscVVf53A0K9BcqFYISA9z8C+l930o6mH7e1T3POvX1f87w/EOWPvYP6QXHXlY8vwswooufO6685R8zfaSD2yapXacIMN1XNf8MJBgK+TJdvvuMug1Bt/vZgEQElfDkMAAQQQkAVOP/Xb3qf6H/biL8oHW3uc/e1jvOUc8boXZ5XjCxZNAaHnAujtqcG425iPnPiJtdr3YHH1/4N/f4LY7tQ6T3vv2j+FeP/yleq4f/5Gdh2pzwUQC655h9Qg3x2r1ESB29w2zzdjdLEEwD2//72694/3qe23fVKwiBtu/o1a8LiN1BMev+aXoUKv1IDXXm7vLqUPbfNdVU/ZV7c1tlw/JZA3/SUBUN8H1CQArrrqqqxC99xzz8H+tTwE0JcAeOChh9Xvl63wNiolAWAfqIN/HcTrJfs6qPc9A0CvCjiuuLK/UbGveZkEgF5NoFcK+B70Z7Lk+hh9S8GrXr3m6eyDl3ALgNlt6pgzZ15p17CvPWXNlXvPwwJjCYDpTZ6sZull/MWVe/tlgvpo8iAhAeAbECkBoI+xl2Y1tfRf16uX1tuvy//3+8P76n190QkD87A9vT22FD/rExPZedasWWqLLbdSq4qgf3bx3ybo//GlPxz+9w8uOk+98GWHDUrRV/1ZAVCXPuUggAACCLgC+hYA++n9ezx94WDpf9VfATDlvPlthyejpwTUuc8FkCr3JQB0Mv4Df/9+6dDkpIMvAfBAkQB4Y8kEgG95/SgfRihCFDtICQC3DHfZv94eK8PXhrbON2MesQSATizdfMtt6ik77xAs4ppfLlbbb7fN4HYU6RUL7vWxbsAdC6rdbfp4E8…tAtypQdEGv+UdcXAQIECBA4usDRCuajzefo19/e53fUAGDv65IqLo8wL3NoEzhMABCbdu6T/v740qfwYXEeOye1O6B2+3/fpgCg7cJ1NAECBAgQWErgaAXz0eaz1Lprdx4BAcA8jku0MuZ+8SXGoc3rCuw6ACjd1x8W77WfwIfL0bK1f/h8AAHAdS9svRMgQIAAgbECRyuYjzafsevqvHUEBADrOI/pRQAwRu145xwiAIh9ZWCqAC/dAjBc4lwIMNz2353bfxvA8FsBap9tUHvc8S5FMyJAgAABAtsQOFrBfLT5bOMqMYqUgADAtUFg2wICgLtf39f91D4EsF/O0u6AsM0+GOjPbX0I4bYvIaMjQIAAAQLHElijYH71a157eeyjH7mBC/97Cck15hOO+13v+dHL2//OW6JTyb1WO/c52qjta67j9jjmsXMXAIyVcx6BdQR2GwDUfFJeenp/WJjXfg3g2ABgGAKEy1vzrIJ1Lge9ECBAgAABAmsUzEsX/eEqrjEfAUD+fSMA8HeFAIGtCAgABjsAUoV6zW0GsUBhuNDD5xa03pKwlQvHOAgQIECAwFEFxhTMXUHf//Sf7Pf/7l8LP/EPj+3DgGEoMNwlkGq/tA5j5lNqs3u9K2r7n/AT/2Gx2x/XHZN6rWtnuGsg1n6qz5rxznVMbA792GvHnJvHFuY4xcoOgCl6ziWwvMDmAoDlp6wHAgQIECBAgEBaoLVgLhXusa3+sVsAUu3k2q9Zx9b51LRZKoLDgnhYHMde6wOFMa/VjHfOY1JzH2PSMu8557BkWwKAJXW1TWC6gABguqEWCBAgQIAAgQMJTC2Ya+7vTx0T2w1wlACgpdhd+jkCUy/XfnzhOJcIAKaO8xrnCwCuoa5PAvUCAoB6K0cSIECAAAECJxAYEwCEtwB0RKUH/LUGAEP24W0GuWUZM5/SMs9V7A77Gd5K0L+eu8WgNNYlXp8aAIyZ9xLzWKJNAcASqtokMJ+AAGA+Sy0RIECAAAECBxBoLZhrbwEIaVoDgJaCf7gErfOpWcK5AoDUtwUMx5D7pL1mvHMfMzUAGDPvueewVHsCgKVktUtgHgEBwDyOWiFAgAABAgQOItBaMMce1ld7339HVtriX3q9xN46n1J73etLBABjttPXjHWpY3IGQ6Oxc9vjtwcIAJa64rRLYB4BAcA8jlohQIAAAQIEDiIwpmAOn/QfK9g7mvBT/NLxqW8SGLZTQz5mPjXttn4LQN9mzTb/voDOnVP7KXrNXMYcEyvOcyZdH7lvC+jH4FsAxqyGcwgQqBUQANRKOY4AAQIECBA4hcBSBfO18I42n2s56rdOwA6AOidHEbiWgADgWvL6JUCAAAECBDYpcLSC+Wjz2eRFY1D3BAQALgYC2xYQAGx7fYyOAAECBAgQWFngaAXz0eaz8uWgu0YBAUAjmMMJrCwgAFgZXHcECBAgQIDAtgWOVjAfbT7bvnqMTgDgGiCwbQEBwLbXx+gIECBAgACBlQWOVjAfbT4rXw66axQQADSCOZzAygICgJXBdUeAAAECBAhsW+BoBfPR5rPtq8foBACuAQLbFhAAbHt9jI4AAQIECBBYWeBoBfPR5rPy5aC7RgEBQCOYwwmsLCAAWBlcdwQIECBAgMC2BY5WMB9tPtu+eoxOAOAaILBtAQHAttfH6AgQIECAAIGVBY5WMB9tPitfDrprFOgCAD8ECGxX4KVf9e2TBnfrzt2fSS04mQABAgQIECCwIYGjFcxHm8+GLhVDIUCAwO4EnnrqqUljFgBM4nMyAQIECBAgsDWBoxXMR5vP1q4X4yFAgMCeBAQAe1otYyVAgAABAgQWFzhawXy0+Sx+AeiAAAECBxYQABx4cU2NAAECBAgQaBc4WsF8tPm0r6gzCBAgQKAXEAC4FggQIECAAAECgcDRCuajzcfFSoAAAQLjBQQA4+2cSYAAAQIECBxQ4GgF89Hmc8BLzpQIECCwmoAAYDVqHREgQIAAAQJ7EDhawXy0+ezhGjJGAgQIbFXgqgFA9/+Q/BAgQIAAAQIEtiTwFV/+/MtLb79kS0OaNJbPf+ELl089Oe1rnyYNwMmrCrzqlS9ftT+dESCwL4GrBgD7ojJaAgQIECBAgAABAgQIECCwXwEBwH7XzsgJECBAgAABAgQIECBAgEC1gACgmsqBBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIEBgvwICgP2unZETIECAAAECBAgQIECAAIFqAQFANZUDCRAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIDAfgUEAPtdOyMnQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQLVAgKAaioHEiBAgAABAgQIECBAgACB/QoIAPa7dkZOgAABAgQIECBAgAABAgSqBQQA1VQOJECAAAECBAgQIECAAAEC+xUQAOx37YycAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAhUCwgAqqkcSIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIE9isgANjv2hk5AQIECBAgQIAAgU0J3Hrbo5saj8EQIHC/wKd/6NWTSG7dufszqQUnEyBAgAABAgQIECBwCAEBwCGW0SQOLCAAOPDimhoBAgQIECBAgACBNQUEAGtq64tAu4AAoN3MGQQIECBAgAABAgQIRAQEAC4LAtsWEABse32MjgABAgQIECBAgMBuBAQAu1kqAz2pgADgpAtv2gQIECBAgAABAgTmFhAAzC2qPQLzCggA5vXUGgECBAgQIECAAIHTCggATrv0Jr4TAQHAThbKMAkQIECAAAECBAhsXUAAsPUVMr6zCwgAzn4FmD8BAgQIECBAgACBmQQEADNBaobAQgICgIVgNUuAAAECBAgQIEDgbAICgLOtuPnuTUAAsLcVM14CBAgQIECAAAECGxUQAGx0YQyLwDMCAgCXAgECBAgQIECAAAECswgIAGZh1AiBxQQEAIvRapgAAQIECBAgQIDAuQQEAOdab7Pdn4AAYH9rZsQECBAgQIAAAQIENikgANjkshgUgXsCAgAXAwECBAgQIECAAAECswgIAGZh1AiBxQQEAIvRapgAAQIECBAgQIDAuQTOEgDcefdDNwubmm//es0xc5qVxlV7NYbjz82htj3HxQXmWq8W31gA8PDDDyebeOSRR+577daduz8tHTqWAAECBAgQIECAAIFjCsxZzG5ZqFS47TkAGBb/AoDlrsTSdbREz6kdALEQYFj831wLAoAllkWbBAgQIECAAAECBPYnIAC4XMKiLlfgLVH8zdHmHG3s78q9zoivYZ27BSAMAWLFvwDgOteJXgkQIECAAAECBAhsUuAsAUCHnyreagKApQq/Odqdo41NXpwbHNQ1rEvPAOhCgFTxLwDY4EVkSAQIECBAgAABAgSuJSAAqNsBUAoPwvUbmsYChpvC7G2PFkOJ/rjY9RHb+h9rN3V7Q82tA6mxh+Oa8vyBucdQ84yHlGk3ltj5qYCoZt5T5tePpRQAlP52uAWgJOR1AgQIECBAgAABAicREAA8HQCEDrFCMBYApArwYYFZW6j3l1zN8wi6Y2vaHV7G/Tynjn0YNKT6Sb2Ncv3X+vVt54KUmGksAMiZ50KQ3LynGgsATvJH2DQJECBAgAABAgQIrCVw9gAgV9gPQ4FUYVp7XK7wjBXmtWtTCidKn2oPi+TYfHJFeWn+sWu5tKOiZQxDu5odGKljSmtU2k1RshizVnYArPXXUD8ECBAgQIAAAQIEDi5QW2QegWHOYj93L/jwtdpjaz/5H65F7bxyhX7qtZZCvWsjN9eaa6hlLrXONcf1uz5iu0HCUKDWo3bNS2ZdO0899VQNXfIYtwBM4rtcXv2a197XwmMf/cjEFttP78ZQ22/LseFIWs5rObZ9tuucEc6hNJ/S6zUjnqONmn5qjknNfUtj7OaxtfHEbPcwxtI10fJeKLU19fX+723N37s92E8dY+35tceNXZ9wXea8XlrWe+zYlz6v1b71+KXHP/Z/B5T+Hm5lnqVxlF5f03/Nvs4UAMSKrZqCs+aYcM1qCs7++Ng28dY1mTq+MWOvLYRrr+WhQ+mT9Nxadq/lzs+tT2ntaued2/7fm5R2LvRzFADUXkUzH5f6HyZz/D+LOdpITXeOtudoY+blWLS50nxLr9cMbmobU8+vuV6W6qPGZ6/HLG22dPud+xp91KxvaRzD10vH1/S59DFTxzj1/DnmlxvDlPFNOXeOedX8Tazpp3UercfXjKH2mFLfpddL/Uw9v9R+zet7/DtRM6+5j2ktNufuf+32wgKu9lPaqQV2TT9Dh5Z1mTq+sO9SAdwfW1sI59Y3VySPCQD6grn7v6XiOnUdlK6P2nlvKgD49Kc/fWftN5r+CBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAgTaBT37yk20nDI6+JQCY5OdkAgQIECBAgAABAgQIECCwisDVA4APfehDq0xUJwQIECBAgAABAgQIECCwXYHXv/712x3cQUYmADjIQpoGAQIECBAgQIAAAQIE9iwgAFh+9QQAyxvrgQABAgQIECBAgAABAgQKAgKA5S+RVQKAD3zgA5c3velN0dm4BWD5RdYDAQIECBAgQIAAAQIEti4gABi/Qg8//PDlkUceKTaweADQFf/djwCguBYOIECAAAECBAgQIECAwGkFBADjl74LALqfUgiwaADQF/8CgPEL6UwCBAgQIECAAAECBAicQUAAMH6V+wCgFAIsFgCExb8AYPxCOpMAAQIECBAgQIAAAQJnEBAAjF/lMADIhQCLBQBdp3YAjF9AZxIgQIAAAQIECBAgQOBMAgKA8at99R0A/dA9A2D8IjqTAAECBAgQIECAAAECZxEQAIxf6U08AyAMATwEcPxiOpMAAQIECBAgQIAAAQJHFxAAjF/hzXwLQGkKvgawJOR1AgQIECBAgAABAgQIHF9AALD8Gi/6DICa4QsAapQcQ4AAAQIECBAgQIAAgWMLCACWX9+rBwDLT1EPBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAgADANUCAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBE4gMDUA+P/IpB0eVS88mAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==");

data[0].push("data:image/png;base64,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…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");
```

Comment: Provide sample array,or some code

Comment: added an array sample

Comment: don't know why this was closed as too broad:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32096540/merge-two-datauris-to-create-a-single-image/50658710#50658710

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am actually over thinking this. I have dimensions and data uri, I just need to draw them out on a canvas and get the canvas uri

Comment: Good idea. Forget what I said :)

Answer (score 0):

Certainly it is *possible*, but will require understanding of the underlying file format. I do not believe this will be as simple as concatenating two strings.

The PNG file format has several variations. For instance, it can store 24-bit color images, or 8-bit images that use a color lookup table.

If you study the PNG file format, certainly JavaScript could be used to manipulate the contents and write the image data out to a page or for downloading.